# How to search and display text files in c++

Tags: c++

I just want to make a list of text files in a certain directory and display them in order to be accessed individually by a user.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Use the boost filesystems library.

Answer (score -1):

You can use FindFirstFile and FindNextFile windows API's to find the text files in a folder.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. We can use these API's to find the files in a folder.

Comment: uhmm.. is there another way? i just want to create a simple program.

Comment: @AnilKumar: Even on non-Windows systems?

Comment: @GeorgeBobby: That _is_ how you create a simple program (on Windows). Some effort required!

Comment: uhmm. wait, I just want it to display in a console application. Will it work?